# MS Edge: Powershell script to open three SEPARATE/independent MS Edge Windows (not tabs!)

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge, chromium

I working on a network operations center type setup.  On this particular PC, I have eight monitors.  I have some software that will POSITION certain windows on certain monitors just after they launch.   That's not my problem.

My problem is that each of the eight monitors needs to display a full screen instance of MS Edge.  When I launch edge from a powershell script, each new launch of the application starts in a TAB of the FIRST instance of MS Edge  instead of a completely independent window.

I'm using a powershell script like this as an example:

```
[system.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("msedge","https://something.com/somefile1.aspx")
[system.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("msedge","https://somethingelse.com/somefile2.aspx")
```

...however I'm open to using whatever powershell script syntax accomplishes my stated goal.

These open up in tabs instead of independent MS Edge application windows.   Since this is in a NOC, I need to be able to script this independent of any windows user-specific settings - I need to be able to start the windows the same way regardless of which person is actually logging in.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--new-window` switch

```
Start-Process -FilePath msedge -ArgumentList '--new-window www.google.com'
Start-Process -FilePath msedge -ArgumentList '--new-window www.bing.com'
```

Comment: Along with Daniel's helpful answer, vs the separate commands, you could just pass in a list. ```'microsoft.com','stackoverflow.com' | ForEach-Object {Start-Process -FilePath msedge -ArgumentList "-new-window $PSitem"}``` This way you can just create a text file and read them in for processing as needed.

Comment: Thank you, postanote!   I think i will use this suggestion as well!